# pip version is old in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am using Python3 with the console of Visual Code.
When I create a virtual environment the pip version is always outdated.
I cannot understand from where the outdated version of pip is coming from.
I have the same version of Python in Windows and in the virtual environment.

```
 > py
 Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 >>> exit()

 > .\.tempcollect\Scripts\activate
 (.tempcollect) > py 
 Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

But for pip it is not the case

```
> pip --version
pip 20.3.1 from c:\users\20000263\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

 > .\.tempcollect\Scripts\activate
 (.tempcollect) > pip --version
 pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\20000263\documents\dev\tempcollect\.tempcollect\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

After creating a virtual env, I manually upgrade pip to the lastest version but I would like to avoid to have to do it systematically.